# How to Bind to a property defined in code-behind from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to a `FoundationHeight` clr-property defined in code-behind.

**xaml**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FoundationHeight}"/>
```

**c#**

```
public double FoundationHeight { get; set; }
public AssignColumnPropertiesWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FoundationHeight = 60;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `RelativeSource`.

If the code-behind is defined for your UserControl:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=FoundationHeight}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just add this line to constructor of the window

```
public AssignColumnPropertiesWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = this;

    FoundationHeight = 60;
}
```

and your `Binding` will work